# connect amazon mysql with JDBC through remote server

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, jsch

I had a problem here, is it possible that JDBC connecting to the amazon MySQL server remotely? I searching on the Internet for solution but ended up receiving the error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I am using jsch.jar to connect the remote server, then call up JDBC connector trying to connect MySQL DB, I had successfully connected to the remote server yet I cannot connect MySQL DB on amazon, here is my code

```
testPutty t = new testPutty();
        t.connect("admin", "", "xx:xx:xx:xx", "openSSHPrivateKey", 22);
        t.connect();
        System.out.println("connected");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://staging.ppyhcsxnlkji.ap-southwest-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/staging","superuser","password");
        System.out.println("hello world");
        t.close();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Are you attempting to establish a connection to a MySQL server over an ssh tunnel? If so you'd need to specify the tunnel configuration (local and remote ports) when setting up the ssh connection, and then connect to that port on _localhost_.  If not, then it's not clear why you need the ssh connection.

Comment: yes exactly what you are saying, but I have no idea how to specify the tunnel. Please guide me with sample code as I just started explore SSH with jsch.jar

Comment: Read the SSH man page for the command line options.  An outgoing tunnel is set up with `-Lnnnn:host:mmmm` where `nnnn` is the local port, `host` is the host to connect to at the far end, and `mmmm` is the remote port.  What is `testPutty`? Is that a wrapper you wrote for command-line putty? BTW, class names in Java should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: the command line options works fine with PuTTY, what Im trying here is connecting with Java mysql-connector.jar, i had successfully connected to the server but mysql database is on amazon must through the server IP.

The way I establish the connection is not working causing Communications link failure, anything I specifying wrongly?
`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://staging.ppyhcsxnlkji.ap-southwest-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/staging","superuser","password");`

Comment: You are misunderstanding how SSH tunneling works. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up the tunnel with SSH.  You haven't shown what `testPutty` is so I'll assume it's a thin Java wrapper around a command line invocation of Putty.  The command line option for setting up a tunnel is

```
-L[localport]:[host]:[remoteport]
```

For your example this would be

```
-L3306:staging.ppyhcsxnlkji.ap-southwest-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

This sets up a tunnel that forwards connections to local port 3306 to port 3306 on the given host (`staging...amazonaws.com`) on port 3306, routed through the host that is the target of the SSH command (in your sample `xx:xx:xx:xx`).

Then, your connection string needs to use `localhost` instead of the actual remote:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staging
```

If 3306 on your local host is not available because you are also running a local copy of MySQL, just choose a different unused port.